# Is is possible to create the following dynaic SQL query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Given this `sells` table (in `MySQL`):

```
id | person   | state | amount
 1 |  Ringo   |   CA  |  3$
 2 |  Paul    |   CA  |  10$
 3 |  John    |   MA  |  2$
 4 |  Ringo   |   CA  |  6%   
 5 |  Ringo   |   MA  |  12$
```

We like to create an SQL to get, for each `person`, what was his **latest**  amount he sold in each state - something like that:

```
person | CA  |  MA 
 Ringo |  6$ |  12$
 Paul  |  10$|   -
 John  |   - |  2$
```

We also like this query to be dynamic enough, so if there will be a new record with a new state (e.g. TX), we will get it automatically.

```
6 | George  | TX | 15$
```

Will result in:

```
person | CA  |  MA   | TX
 Ringo |  6$ |  12$  | -
 Paul  |  10$|   -   | -
 John  |   - |  2$   | -
 George|   - |  -    | 15$
```

We tried `Group by` with this query:

```
select * from sells where id in(
   select max(id) from sells 
   group by person, state
 )
```

That seems to bring the right data for our needs, but we need help to do the extra leap to our wanted result

Comment: As mentioned, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get all the data you need with simpler SQL and format further in your application code to get the format that you want.

Table where for there is one row for each state a person has spent on:

```
id | person   | state | amount
 4 |  Ringo   |   CA  |  6$
 5 |  Ringo   |   MA  |  12$  
 2 |  Paul    |   CA  |  10$
 3 |  John    |   MA  |  2$
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT id, person, state, amount
FROM sells
GROUP BY person, state
HAVING id = MAX(id)
```